# Display inline or negative margin

Tags: css

I am using a `<h2>` tag for my titles. Underneath, I have a `<hr />` tag. The space between the title and the `<hr />` is too big.

Would I use `display: inline;` on the `<h2>` tag, negative `margin-top` on the `<hr />`, or even something else?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to use the `<hr />` as an underline?  A horizontal rule is meant for separating content.  What you should be using is a border-bottom on the h2.

Comment: Yes. The `<hr />` is 2 lines, a white and a gray one. How would I do that using `border-bottom`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `hr` element between a heading and the content it's introducing. (*)

Better use CSS:

```
h2 {
    border-bottom: 2px groove white;
}
```

than using a structural element for styling purposes.

(*) Its semantics is more like [end of one section, start of another](http://html5doctor.com/small-hr-element/#element-hr) (according to Hixie via HTML5doctor). I've used it quite a lot for my past year project but frankly you can also live without... ;) It's also quite hard to style it cross-browser, that doesn't help at all!

EDIT: OP cared about the default rendering of hr, found a better way than my initial styling `1px solid #CCC` with its `2px groove white` (see comments below), its edit got rejected but it's fine to me so I edited my answer anyway.

Comment: Note that if you want it to look like a horizontal rule, you'd want to use `border-bottom: 2px inset #CCC`.  Personally, I think 1px solid borders look nicer.

Comment: The `<hr />` is 2 lines, a white and a gray one. How would I do that using the `border-bottom`?

Comment: @cimmanon Thanks for the inset keyword! Couldn't remember what's the best way to do this sort of bi-color borders as I rarely have to design that. Or when it happens it's between horizontal list items...

Comment: I figured it out. `border-bottom: 2px groove white;` made it look identical :-) Thank you for your time

Comment: Ah great. Couldn't make inset work in Firefox on a fiddle. Other methods I can think of: border-bottom on h2 and border-top on `h2+p` (if both elements have the same width and beware of margins. Compatibility IE7+ or add a class to the first p after h2 if you need IE6 support); also text-shadow will let you do this but its compatibility isn't as good

Comment: OP your edit got rejected but it seems fine to me so I edited my answer anyway ;)